Okta session timeout not working with Spring Boot OAuth2/OIDC - users stay logged in
I'm integrating Okta with my Spring Boot application for user authentication using OAuth2 login and OIDC. I have set the following session policies in Okta

The expectation is that if a user remains inactive in the browser for
1 minute, they should be logged out automatically and prompted to log
in again via Okta. However, this isn't happening as expected. Even
after 1 minutes of inactivity, users remain logged in.

spring boot code
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
            .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()) 
        )
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
            authorizeRequests
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2Login(oauth2 ->
            oauth2
                .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo ->
                    userInfo
                        .oidcUserService(oidcUserService()) 
                )
        );

    return http.build();
}

Controller
@RestController
public class UserController {

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String getToken(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println("Authorities: " + authentication.getAuthorities());
    return "Authorities: " + authentication.getAuthorities();
  }

  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PAD')")
  @GetMapping("/user")
  public String getUser() {
    return "Hello World";
  }

  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('CAD')")
  @GetMapping("/usertest")
  public String getUserTest() {
    return "Hello World";
  }

Am I missing something in my Spring Boot configuration to enforce Okta's session timeout? Should Spring Boot manage sessions differently, or is it entirely handled by Okta? How can I ensure that after 1 minutes of inactivity, users are forced to log in again?
To configure your Spring Boot application to rely solely on the Okta session timeout settings for invalidating sessions

You got the problem correct. Okta session will be terminated but not the one in your application. I'd try to look into Spring Boot OIDC logout support and then configure OIDC logout URL in your application in Okta, so that when your session in Okta is terminated the app will be notified on the back-channel

so what is the configuration i need to do it in spring boot. code ?

https://github.com/prabagaran-sellamuthu/OktaDemo

@PhilippGrigoryev Okta session will be terminated ? how i can verify this one

From the front end perspective you can verify by termination of your app local session and trying to log in again. If Okta session is still present, then you won't be asked for Okta credentials. Other way is just to open your Okta in another tab of your browser after that and seeing if you are asked for your credentials.

Does Okta support back-channel logout configuration? I can't find that option in the Okta admin console. Additionally, even though I set the session timeout to one minute, I don’t see any logs for termination requests after the user is idle or inactive in the browser and hasn’t made any requests to Okta. I thought that if no request is made to Okta, the session would terminate and that would be logged in OKTA application logs

it's in EA now, but here is the link to the doc - https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/single-logout/main/
